# How to run Jenkins jobs on multiple slaves with a single job configuration?

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, devops

I have three different environments each containing a Jenkins Slave,

**STAGE1** - `slave1`
**STAGE2** - `slave2`
**STAGE3** - `slave3`

I don't want to create three different build jobs for them.

I want to pass the slaves (`slave1`, `slave2` and `slave3`) as parameters, so that if I choose `slave1` the job gets executed on **STAGE1**, and if I choose `slave2` the job gets executed on **STAGE2** and so on.

How to achieve that using a single Jenkins job?

I know there is multi configuration job but I am not clear on how to configure it.

It would be really helpful if I get some information on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. It can be achieved using,

> [Node and Label Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)

It lets you create node and label parameter in the job configuration.

Node parameter contains all the nodes present in your Jenkins including master, you can select the nodes you want.

When you run the job with parameters you can select the desired node and the job will get executed in that particular node.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in test automation where I need to maintain different environment and deploy jobs to Jenkins, I'm not sure it would be helpful, if it is I will share code snippet(If required).

I am not doing exact thing for environment but I've achieved this thing fro browsers, I am using maven as my build tool so I've made configuration in my code that it will fetch the same browser I'm passing in the command which is set as a goal for single Jenkins job.

```
Goal example: mvn clean verify -Dtest=test.xml -Dbrowser=chrome
```

Same can be done for multiple environments as well, you can set a default slave in POM file and make changes configurations changes or you can create 3 multiple files like XML which will contain your executable files and add them as parameter in Jenkins single job.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to achieve to trigger same job in the multiple servers(nodes/slaves) simultaneously with the help of below configuration.

First you have to create the project as below shown below in the screeshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Emz.png)

Then configure the details as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eg7H.png)

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others